# Spark: Input a vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm get into spark and I have problems with Vectors
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}

The input of my program is a text file with contains the output of a RDD(Vector): 
dataset.txt:

```
[-0.5069793074881704,-2.368342680619545,-3.401324690974588]
[-0.7346396928543871,-2.3407983487917448,-2.793949129209909]
[-0.9174226561793709,-0.8027635530022152,-1.701699021443242]
[0.510736518683609,-2.7304268743276174,-2.418865539558031]
```

So, what a try to do is:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/workingdirectory/dataset")
val data = rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
```

I have the error because it read [0.510736518683609 as a number. 
Exist any form to load directly the vector stored in the text-file without doing the second line? How I can delete "[" in the map stage ? 
I'm really new in spark, sorry if it's a very obvious question.

Answer (score 4):

Given the input the simplest thing you can do is to use `Vectors.parse`:

```scala
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

scala> Vectors.parse("[-0.50,-2.36,-3.40]")
res14: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [-0.5,-2.36,-3.4]
```

It also works with sparse representation:

```scala
scala> Vectors.parse("(10,[1,5],[0.5,-1.0])")
res15: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = (10,[1,5],[0.5,-1.0])
```

Combining it with your data all you need is:

```scala
rdd.map(Vectors.parse)
```

If you expect malformed / empty lines you can wrap it using `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try

rdd.map(line => Try(Vectors.parse(line))).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
```

Comment: I didn't even know that method exists! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it :

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/workingdirectory/dataset")
val data = rdd.map {
   s => 
    val vect = s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").split(',').map(_.toDouble)
    Vectors.dense(vect)
}
```

I've just broke the map into line for readability purpose.

**Note:** Remember, it's simple a string processing on each line.

Comment: How about `drop(1).dropRight(1).split(",").map(_.toDouble)` or `val p = "-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?".r;  p.findAllIn(s).map(_.toDouble)`?

Comment: That's why I said one way! :)